# Fallback to default script if pretty url router could not fing a match

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am implementing a pretty url router for my (php) application.
Here is what I placed in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.+)? url_router.php
```

in url_router.php, I parse the requested url and see if a module has requested to capture the pretty url. If no match is made, I want to fetch the actual ur requested, for example,

- If the requested url is /core/admin.php and url_router.php doesn't recognize it as a pretty url for processing, I want the actual admin.php at /core/ to be executed.
- If the requested url is /blog/sample-post and I have a module blog which wants to take control. So now the content is served by the blog module.

I have already implemented how the router calls other modules, but could not figure out how to fallback to default url when the router doesn't find a match

Comment: Is */core/admin.php* not a pretty url because it finishes by *.php* ? If so, url_router.php should check if the requested url finishes by *.php* and redirect to it (with `header('Location: ...');`) else do your business with controller.

Comment: won't redirecting to /core/admin.php again cause the rewrite engine to redirect again to url_router.php and then cause an infinite loop?

Comment: Oh yeah, and change .htaccess and add a condition to detect `(.php)$`

Comment: But files ending with .php is the only criteria for redirecting or not. (sorry, forgot to reply in the first comment)

Comment: Then, can you edit the question and add criterias involved ?

Comment: Ok, let me put it this way: the router makes an sql query to get a list of regex patterns (which are inserted there by the modules). If one of the pattern matches, then it's fine. Otherwise, I want it to fallback to the requested url and proceed.

I can't add all the patterns to .htaccess as the modules are added/removed/updated by the app admin as he likes. And I don't want to edit .htaccess everytime.